# Is there a method to ignore the file name case senstivity in Qt c++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4.8, qfile

I want to save two different files with the same name, each varrying only in the UpperCase and LowerCase. I am using windows. Is there a function in C++ Qt to ignore the case sensitivity ?

Comment: Use [`QString::toLower()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLower)

Comment: Windows won't allow you, with Qt or any other API.

Comment: Filenames exposed by regular WinAPI functions are not case sensitive, even though usual file systems, such as NTFS are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows already ignores case sensitivity**, so you don't have to do anything to ignore it as long as you execute your code on Windows.

The problem is when you need to make the difference between two paths relying on the case sensitivity. You really should avoid to have files with the same name in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Windows API usually does not allow creating files with case-sensitive names, even though, the NTFS filesystem itself supports this.

However, there is that function `CreateFileA` in the API, which can be invoked with the flag `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS`, which allows to access files whose names only differ in case.
However, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) also states:

> Access will occur according to POSIX rules. This includes allowing multiple files with names, differing only in case, for file systems that support that naming. Use care when using this option, because files created with this flag may not be accessible by applications that are written for MS-DOS or 16-bit Windows.

I don't know, how other applications, like the Windows explorer, will behave when encountering such files.